# Adobe Air aspect ratio not working on iPad

Tags: actionscript-3, ipad, flash, air, adobe

[image: screenshot]

So we're using Adobe Air to develop iPad games from Flash for an educational kiosk that we're building. The issue is that some of the games are in portrait mode, and some of them look best in landscape mode. To account for this, we've ordered a swiveling kiosk that users can turn to either orientation depending on the game. All of the games are opened from a central app that we've developed as a "launcher" for them, so they're opened from within that other app instead of from the iOS home screen.

I'm using the "Aspect Ratio" command when publishing the game and setting to portrait or landscape depending on which game it is. I'm also setting the "Auto-Orientation" to false (though I've tried it on true as well and had similar issues). However, the two landscape games are showing up incorrectly as you can see in the image below. How can I force those games to show up properly on the iPad?

Answer (score 0):

Keep auto orientation = false. Create your 'portrait' games on a portrait-oriented stage. Now create your 'landscape' games on that same portrait-oriented stage. Make them at their proper scale, so that they run off the stage. You can use a temporary landscape-stage-sized rectangle, on the lowest layer, to represent a proper landscape-oriented stage that you can compose on top of.  When your game is all laid out select all layers and rotate the whole magilla 90-degrees. Presto! You just rotate the Pad to play the landscape games.

You may have to switch 'width' and 'height' references in your code for those games, and also 'x' and 'y' references. If you have many of those some simple matrix math will help with the transposition.